# Instalação My SQL

Tags: mysql, instalador

Estou instalando o MySQL Server na minha máquina seguindo o passo a passo, porém finalizo a instalação não aparece o Wizard de configuração do servidor (MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard).

Também não encontro ele em Iniciar > Todos os programas > MySQL > MySQL Server 5.6

Como posso iniciá-lo para fazer as configurações e começar a utilizar?

Comment: Pedro, você executou a instalação com privilégios de administrador? Se não apareceu nada, ou você instalou a partir de um ZIP ou a instalação não foi concluída com sucesso.

Comment: Já instalei novamente e nada. Na pasta que citei só aparecem dois arquivos MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client

Comment: Olá, você tentou usar o instalador completo do MySQL?
32 bits: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=451431
64 bits: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=451432

Comment: Obrigado, baixei outro instalador e funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

**1- verifique os serviços instalados por MySQL.** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**2- Verifique se o serviço do MySQL foi instalado e qual e o estado dele(parado ou iniciado)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]